# Grafana group series

Tags: postgresql, grafana

I have postgres table with three variables: datetime, robot_id and energy_percent. Now at chart I have `energy_percent` and `robot_id`. How to group records from this table by `robot_id` ? Currently at this table I have records with 3 different `robot_id`, so I want see 3 lines on this chart.
[image]

Edit:
I have one table with a lot records, at column `robot_id` I have ids. I need one line chart per one unique `robot_id`. If table contains `x` unique`robot_id` I expect `x` lines on chart. Here is sample at excel: on left is wrong chart, at right is correct chart:
[image]
And moreover one thing: on excel where is no data I have 0, but I need no point.

Edit2: I can do it with a lot of series as below, but it should be universal (idk how many unique `robot_id` will be) and done with one Query (A) not a lot of queries (A,B,C, etc.)

[image]

Edit 3:
When I apply code:

```
SELECT
  $__timeGroupAlias(time_created, $__interval),
  robot_id AS "metric",
  AVG(energy_percent) AS "value"
FROM api_robotlog
WHERE
  $__timeFilter(time_created)
GROUP BY 1,2
ORDER BY 1
```

I have 2 plots: `energy_percent(time)` and `robot_id(time)`. There is no a lot of plots `energy_percent(time, robot_id)`.
[image]

Edit 5:
Using @Jan Garaj solution it working. Two charts, with two similar queries:
[image]
TOP chart query:

```sql
SELECT
  $__timeGroupAlias(time_created, $__interval),
  robot_id AS "metric",
  AVG(energy_percent) AS "value"
FROM api_robotlog
WHERE
  $__timeFilter(time_created)
GROUP BY 1,2
ORDER BY 1
```

BOTTOM chart query:

```sql
SELECT
  $__timeGroupAlias(time_created, $__interval),
  robot_id::varchar AS "metric",
  AVG(energy_percent) AS "value"
FROM api_robotlog
WHERE
  $__timeFilter(time_created)
GROUP BY 1,2
ORDER BY 1
```

Comment: Not sure how you would do it with one query, easiest would be to use 3 queries for that panel and filter in the `WHERE` clause for a different `robot_id` each. Guess thats only an option if no new ids are added dynamically.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just group it properly. I would switch to text edit more and write SQL manually. For example:

```
SELECT
  $__timeGroupAlias(time_created, $__interval),
  robot_id AS "metric",
  AVG(energy_percent) AS "value"
FROM api_robotlog
WHERE
  $__timeFilter(time_created)
GROUP BY 1,2
ORDER BY 1
```

Comment: Thank You, we are close enough, I edit question and add more precision information about expected chart

Comment: @sosnus I gave you generic answer = one query which generates timeseries for each robot_id. You didn't follow my answer, but you followed a comment which has advised to create separate queru per each robot_id.

Comment: I follow You query, but output looks like `Edit3` on Question post. With this query I do not receive a lot of `energy_percent(time)` plots

Comment: @sosnus Pls use the latest Grafana version (8.4.X+)

Comment: I have `v8.5.0 (6134e3cf35)`, it is enough?

Comment: @sosnus Cast `robot_id` as string, e.g. `robot_id::varchar AS "metric",` Grafana is picky on the datatype sometimes

Comment: Amazing! now with `robot_id::varchar AS "metric",` it working properly ;)